# What happens when virtualenv and system site packages have conflicting dependencies?

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

If your virtual environment has package `X` that depends on, say, `numpy-1.12`, and your system site has package `Y` that depends on, say, `numpy-1.8`, what happens when you do

```
import X
import Y
```

or

```
import Y
import X
```

?

(Assuming you either created the virtual environment using

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages
```

or symlinked `Y`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's at install time that dependencies are resolved, not at import time.  Hence the order of the statements `import X` and `import Y` in the source code is irrelevant and immaterial to your question.

The package which is installed in the virtualenv would win here, because that will be the first time numpy is found when traversing `sys.path`.  Checking the attribute `numpy.__file__` will tell you where it was picked up from, and you can run `python -m site` to see the details of why `numpy` would be picked up from that location first.

Realistically, packages usually don't specify a dependency hard-pinned to a specific version number, but they specify some range (or don't specify a version restriction at all).